# Are there other names besides dummy index or dummy variable?

Tags: integration, summation, tensor-products, tensors

Has anyone encountered other names than dummy and free variables for indices or integration variables that are summed over.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  Will do ! (:

Comment: And thank you. I had not heard of Mute variable. That's how you say it in french. Is that the case in all latin languages ?

Answer (score 1):

> Dummy variables are also called bound variables or dead variables.
> Comtet (1974) adopts a notation in which dummy variable appearing as
> indices in sums are denoted by placing a dot underneath them (i.e.,
> indicating them with an underdot).

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DummyVariable.html

Comment: oh wow I was not sure I would get an answer and I especially did not expect even a link and quote with a historical story behind ! Thank you very much.